# Click Button To play Animation. ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3

Hi I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
at Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/myPlay_clickHandler()
```

when I execute my code. Can someone please help me, I can't see where I'm going wrong?

```
myAnimation.stop();
myPlayButton.stop();
myPlayButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myPlay_clickHandler);

function myPlay_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent)//Creating function for the Click Event      handler
{
    if(myPlayButton.MovieClip.currentFrame ==1)
    {
        myPlayButton.gotoAndStop(2);
        myAnimation.play();
    }

    trace("myPlay was clicked on");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the 'MovieClip' in 'if (myPlayButton.MovieClip.currentFrame == 1)'. If 'myPlayButton' IS a MovieClip, you can access its currentFrame directly, ie:

```
if (myPlayButton.currentFrame == 1)
```